# UpdateGraph updating associated collection property with parent node

Tags: c#, .net, graphdiff

After using UpdateGraph, if an associated collection has an attribute from the same class as the parent node, this attribute ends up being updated with a reference to the parent node.

The scenario is:

- User class has an ICollection of Team.
- Team has a property named CreatedBy (of type User).
- After using UpdateGraph to add a collection of Teams to a certain user (user.Teams), every Team.CreatedBy is updated with the user that I'm using as parent node.

I created a fiddle for reproducing this problem: https://dotnetfiddle.net/iaC9MW

Anyway, here is the main code snippet for this problem:

```
var user = context.Users.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(q => q.Name == "User_A");
var teams = context.Teams.AsNoTracking().Where(q => q.Name == "Team A").ToList();
user.Teams = teams;

context.UpdateGraph(user, map => map.AssociatedCollection(q => q.Teams));
context.SaveChanges();
```

So after using UpdateGraph/SaveChanges, "Team A".CreatedBy receives "User A", although I didn't specify that.

Here are the definitions of my classes

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Boolean IsActive { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Team> Teams {get; set; }
}

public class Team 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public User CreatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

My attempts:

- I tried to use .Include() for the associated collection
- I tried a few different approaches for adding this team collection.
- I tried also to use List instead ICollection
- I cannot use .OwnedCollection, since any Team may exist by themselves, they're not children of User. Even though, I tried to use that.

All of those attempts ended up on the same result, where Team.CreatedBy gets updated automatically.

If I don't update using GraphDiff, everything works well.

Is there anything wrong on my code? So far, I believe this is a bug on GraphDiff.